# Flutter: Admob - LoadAdError 'no ad to show'

Tags: flutter, admob

```
flutter: LoadAdError(code: 1, domain: com.google.admob, message: Request Error: No ad to show., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: 1uFdYsSBE9SP8AL_jpmABA, mediationAdapterClassName: null, adapterResponses: []))
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x15e004ea0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=57055, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x15e004f00 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=57055, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x15e0042a0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=57056, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x15e004300 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=57056, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
flutter: Ad with id `2` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
flutter: Ad with id `2` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
```

Admob on Android works fine. However, I am getting these errors on the iOS devices. On `Info.plist`, I'd added `SKAdNetworkItems`, `GAD Test Device Code` and `GADApplicationIdentifier`. Both are correctly placed. And, wondering what are the causes of the errors that I am getting. I get that `No ad to show` error can just happen. But, is it normal to receive other errors?

Comment: Did you solve this on your own?

Comment: I don't think I did!